# pixel size requirement for UIButton

Tags: ios

I am creating pixel size button images of width 30 for retina and non retina display.
It looks good. I read in stackoverflow that the pixel requirement for retina is at least 40x40 which looks too big. Will pixel size of 30 caused app rejection?

```
UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnBack setImage:backImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backImage.size.width, backImage.size.height);
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(Click_On_Btn_Back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *backBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarItem;

[btnFollow setImage:followImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnFollow.frame=CGRectMake(followBtnXOffset,currentHeight+followBtnYOffset,followImage.size.width,followImage.size.height);
```

Comment: I think is just a guide line/recommandation. You can make it 1x1 as far as apple is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

Your app won't be rejected for using buttons less than 44x44 pixels. However your users will not appreciate it. There are certainly a few instances where you may need a button smaller than 44x44 and for these its best to subclass and increase the touch area to be 44x44 or larger while the actual image is smaller and centered in that touch area.

Remember that an iPhone uses 163 ppi and an iPad uses 133, while the iPad Mini is 163. So a button that looks a bit large on an iPad will be smaller on iPhones and iPad Minis.

The expectation comes from the iOS Human Interface Guidelines: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41

Answer (score 2):

No it won't be rejected, 40x40 is just Apple's recommendation, so you're free to set any frame you want as long as it's convenient for users.

In fact apple themselves don't follow this recommendation in ios AppStore app (Install/Buy/Free button is ~25px height).